# .NET6 SDK is not working with VS 2022 (Dependency is warning not find the file in Paht)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

[image]

[image]

.NET6 SDK is not working with VS 2022 (Dependency is warning not find the file in Path)

**.csproj (from comments)**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework> 
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable> 
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Please share your .csproj file contents - also try to restart VS

Comment: My .csproj file

<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>